# Proof about σ-algebra

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

For every family A of subsets in X there exists a unique minimal σ-algebra containing A.
How do we prove this ? Can somebody help me please ?

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem? Can you give an example for a $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$?

Answer (score 1):

Does there exist a $\sigma$-algebra containing $A$? Is the intersection of any collection of $\sigma$-algebras also a $\sigma$-algebra?